# Passing data for Curl Function to a Python program on Bash

Tags: python, bash, curl, dictionary

So I'm trying to extract data from the curl function as listed on this Asana API.
https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/projects. The problem is that the data I receive looks like this

{"data":[{"id":"1000","name","first thing"},{"id":"1001","name","second thing"},
{"id":"1002","name","third thing"}]}

This is a great dictionary organized really nicely, but I'm unable to actually use it because bash doesn't recognize this as a dictionary. It is simply reading it as a string. I'm very familiar with python, so I thought if I pass it to a python program it will recognize it as a dictionary, but it doesn't. Please help. All I need is to be able to establish the data as a dictionary and array as it should be. After that I can work with it as I want.

This is what I have so far.

```
   READFILE=$(curl -u $KEY: https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects)
   echo $READFILE
```

if I try to do something like this, however,

```
  for dict in ${READFILE["data"]};
     do echo $dict
  echo ABC
  done
```

bash returns splits the data by white space, so it'll look like this

```
  {"data":[{"id":"1000","name","first
  ABC
  thing"},{"id":"1001","name","second
  ABC
  thing"},{"id":"1002","name","third
  ABC
  thing"}]}
  ABC
```

Similarly if I pass this to a external python script like this

```
  python work.py $READFILE
```

and I try to print like this

```
  import sys
  print(sys.argv);
```

I'll get

```
  {"data":[{"id":"1000","name","first
```

Help me get Python to receive the actual data structure, not just a string split at whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [python api](https://github.com/Asana/python-asana) for asana so you can so it all using python:

```
# basic auth
client = asana.Client.basic_auth('ASANA_API_KEY')

# oauth 2 
client = asana.Client.oauth(
client_id='ASANA_CLIENT_ID',
client_secret='ASANA_CLIENT_SECRET',
redirect_uri='https://yourapp.com/auth/asana/callback'
)
```

There are numerous examples in the link above.